# Why does setting a new attribute initiate a FOUC?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm using `Element.setAttribute` to set an element's `href` attribute after some user input.

I noticed that if I set the `href` on pageload (before user input) to some placeholder value (e.g. empty string), setting the attribute works as expected.

If I don't set the placeholder `href` initially, `setAttribute` has to create the attribute, and I see a FOUC in the button text.

As far as I know, `setAttribute` doesn't trigger a reflow or repaint of the DOM or the element.

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

I understand how to fix it -- I'm just curious why it happens. Can someone tell me what's going on under the hood?

Comment: An `a` element without a `href` attribute is more or less invalid - and specifically, it's not treated as a link by various CSS rules which typically match on `a[href]` not `a` alone.

Comment: @Bergi That makes sense, except that the styles are correctly applied on pageload when the `href` attribute has yet to be applied. It's just during the process of creating the attribute that the FOUC occurs.

Comment: Hm, that's weird indeed.